# Magento/exim emails not arriving, sent to and from own domain

Tags: magento, vps, exim

We have an interesting problem related to Exim. We use Magento.

Emails are being sent by our server to customers and we have the send copy by separate or bcc in backend. We use Google apps MX.

But the email never arrives. If the email is sent to a different email address or domain then it arrives. And if it is the same account:

- sent from: info@domain.com
- to: customer@house.com
- bcc: info@domain.com

the emails don't arrive @ info@domain.com

**Question**: what can this be? I have the idea that exim is not sending the email with info@domain.com to the Google apps MX server for sending

ps. I already read this, but that is OK and not the problem http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/fight-spam-emails/comment-page-1/#comment-53370

Major thanks

UPDATE ADDED MAILLOG

> 2013-07-23 19:55:29 1V1go5-00034h-8G <= domain@domain.com U=domain
>   P=local S=10216 T="Uw bestelling is vandaag verzonden" from
>    for rgoossSNIPPED@gmail.com contact@domain.com
>   2013-07-23 19:55:29 1V1go5-00034h-8G => contact@domain.com
>   F= R=lookuphost T=remote_smtp S=10281
>   H=ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.com [2a00:1450:4013:c01::1a] X=TLSv1:RC4-SHA:128
>   C="250 2.0.0 OK 1374602129 r42si29746715eep.2 - gsmtp" 2013-07-23
>   19:55:30 1V1go5-00034h-8G => rgoossSNIPPED@gmail.com
>   F= R=lookuphost T=remote_smtp S=10281
>   H=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com [2a00:1450:4013:c01::1a]
>   X=TLSv1:RC4-SHA:128 C="250 2.0.0 OK 1374602130 x6si29680305eew.317 -
>   gsmtp" 2013-07-23 19:55:30 1V1go5-00034h-8G Completed
>
> 2013-07-24 10:29:09 1V1uRZ-0005yg-PX <= domain@domain.com U=domain
>   P=local S=10056 T="Uw bestelling is geplaatst en wordt verwerkt" from
>    for SNIPPED@loyenslo-eff.com
>   contact@domain.com 2013-07-24 10:29:10 1V1uRZ-0005yg-PX =>
>   contact@domain.com F= R=lookuphost T=remote_smtp
>   S=10120 H=ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.com [2a00:1450:4013:c00::1b]
>   X=TLSv1:RC4-SHA:128 C="250 2.0.0 OK 1374654550 z6si31979271eel.292 -
>   gsmtp" 2013-07-24 10:29:10 1V1uRZ-0005yg-PX =>
>   SNIPPED@loyenslo-eff.com F= R=lookuphost
>   T=remote_smtp S=10120 H=mail.loyenslo-eff.com [62.132.204.200] C="250
>   ok:  Message 36327691 accepted" 2013-07-24 10:29:10 1V1uRZ-0005yg-PX
>   Completed

And I updated some settings. This is what I am seeing:

```
2013-07-29 14:40:11 1V3mkF-0004vN-Jf <= info@mywebstore.com U=shirts350 P=local S=11736 T="Uw bestelling is geplaatst en wordt verwerkt" from <info@mywebstore.com> for info@mywebstore.com
2013-07-29 14:40:12 1V3mkF-0004vN-Jf => info@mywebstore.com F=<info@mywebstore.com> R=lookuphost T=remote_smtp S=11810 H=ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.com [2a00:1450:4013:c01::1a] X=TLSv1:RC4-SHA:128 C="250 2.0.0 OK 1375101612 3si5304843eej.103 - gsmtp"
2013-07-29 14:40:12 1V3mkF-0004vN-Jf Completed

2013-07-29 14:40:12 1V3mkG-0004vS-1k <= info@mywebstore.com U=shirts350 P=local S=11740 T="Uw bestelling is geplaatst en wordt verwerkt" from <info@mywebstore.com> for mytestemail@gmail.com
2013-07-29 14:40:12 1V3mkG-0004vS-1k => mytestemail@gmail.com F=<info@mywebstore.com> R=lookuphost T=remote_smtp S=11814 H=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com [2a00:1450:4013:c00::1b] X=TLSv1:RC4-SHA:128 C="250 2.0.0 OK 1375101612 e5si53052514eeg.102 - gsmtp"
2013-07-29 14:40:12 1V3mkG-0004vS-1k Completed
```

Comment: Add to your question, the results of 'exigrep info@domain.com /path/to/exim/mainlog' and we'll interpret the results as they are shown.

Comment: The message says that Gmail's server accepted it (the 250 line is the response from their servers).  Have the customer look in their Postini filters, chances are that it's being quarantined before it gets to their mailbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the exim.conf file but this is not The solution. Email from and to The Same domain. And from and to The Same email ard not sent

As I understand it:

The code below looks at local_domains to see of the email is for here, or the outside world. As our email is not handled by the local mail server, but rather google local domains should also be routed via smtp

this line excludes local domains from smtp

domains = ! +local_domains

so we uncommented it

thx

```
# This router routes to remote hosts over SMTP using a DNS lookup. Any domain
# that resolves to an IP address on the loopback interface (127.0.0.0/8) is
# treated as if it had no DNS entry.

lookuphost:
  driver = dnslookup
  # domains = ! +local_domains
  ignore_target_hosts = 127.0.0.0/8
  condition = "${perl{check_limits}}"
  transport = remote_smtp
  no_more
```

Answer (score 1):

I've run into this same problem and this is how I solved it. Instead of changing lookuphost like the other answer, I added another router

In the routers section of my exim conf after the lookuphost router, I added

```
routetogoogle:
  driver = manualroute
  route_list = mydomain.com 
  transport = remote_smtp
```

This manually forces anything going to mydomain.com to use the remote_smtp transport which will look up the correct MX records. Subtle difference from changing lookuphost - but this will allow you to still deliver mail locally for other domains if needed.

Answer (score 0):

I have a magento running in an EC2 instance and for email hosting I am using bluehost, I solve this by setting "**Set Return Path**" to ***Yes*** in **System->Configuration->Advanced->System->Mail Sending Settings**