# trouble with EXIM passing e-mails

Tags: email, smtp, exim, exim4

I am having trouble with EXIM passing e-mails. Domains are fictitious, but work better than using "example" to me.

```
Expected -> device -> relay@insurance.savewiththelizard.com -> payingtoomuch.com
Happening -> device -> relay@insurance.savewiththelizard.com -> vanishes
```

I found this [Magento/exim emails not arriving, sent to and from own domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17807542/magento-exim-emails-not-arriving-sent-to-and-from-own-domain) , but that nor the second answer has resolved my issue.

I have payingtoomuch.com e-mail hosted at GSuite. I have payingtoomuch.com website hosted at insurance.savewiththelizard.com .

When I use relay@insurance.savewiththelizard.com , it will pass to domains that are not hosted locally. Example: I am able to send an e-mail using relay@insurance.savewiththelizard.com to gmail.com, outlook.com, thiscompany.com, but I am not able to send e-mail to payingtoomuch.com . There are no errors when sending the e-mails.

On VestaCP, DNS nor MAIL are installed for payingtoomuch.com on insurance.savewiththelizard.com .

```
payingtoomuch.com
A = 33.33.33.1  [fictitious]
WWW = 33.33.33.1 [fictitious]
MX = aspmx.l.google.com

insurance.savewiththelizard.com SMTP
A = 33.33.33.1  [fictitious]
MX = 33.33.33.1 [fictitious]
```

```
2020-05-07 19:45:53 1jRwFF-0001mO-Ic <= relay@insurance.savewiththelizard.com H=(SERVER218) [X] P=esmtpsa X=TLS1.2:ECDHE_RSA_AES_256_GCM_SHA384:256 CV=no A=dovecot_plain:relay@insurance.savewiththelizard.com S=28773
2020-05-07 19:45:54 1jRwFF-0001mO-Ic => doctor@payingtoomuch.com R=dnslookup T=remote_smtp H=aspmx.l.google.com [172.217.197.26] X=TLS1.2:ECDHE_ECDSA_AES_128_GCM_SHA256:128 CV=yes C="250 2.0.0 OK  1588898754 138si4849187qkm.228 - gsmtp"
2
```

```
2020-05-07 07:03:37 1Wfk3-0001eA-FF <= relay@insurance.savewiththelizard.com H=(EXTRA) [X] P=esmtpsa X=TLS1.2:ECDHE_RSA_AES_256_GCM_SHA384:256 CV=no A=dovecot_plain:relay@insurance.savewiththelizard.com S=38927
2020-05-07 07:03:38 1Wfk3-0001eA-FF => accounting@payingtoomuch.com R=dnslookup T=remote_smtp H=aspmx.l.google.com [209.85.144.27] X=TLS1.2:ECDHE_ECDSA_AES_128_GCM_SHA256:128 CV=yes C="250 2.0.0 OK  1588853018 z5si2008827qtb.399 - gsmtp"
2020-05-07 07:03:38 1Wfk3-0001eA-FF Completed
2
```

The e-mails are not in Junk E-Mail, Spam, etc.

I thought one of these may solve the issue, but it has not.

```
routetotpay:
  driver = manualroute
  route_list = payingtoomuch.com
  transport = remote_smtp
```

```
smart_route:
  driver = manualroute
  route_list = payingtoomuch.com
  transport = remote_smtp
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`exim4.conf.template` file

line:

```
domainlist local_domains = dsearch;/etc/exim4/domains/
```

convert to:

```
domainlist local_domains = !payingtoomuch.com : dsearch;/etc/exim4/domains/
```

restart exim:

```
service exim4 restart
```